# How do I let OpenCV know codecs exist in non-standard locations?

Tags: c++, opencv, codec

I'm working with OpenCV on an HPC cluster that does not have any video codecs. I was able to install Xvid in my home directory but now I don't know how to tell OpenCV where they are in order to open video files with VideoCapture.

Thanks for your help.